# Not able to login to a website using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup, html-parsing

I tried to log in to my university's website through HTML parsing with the Jsoup library in android but apparently, it is not working out.

```
try {



                 Connection.Response response =
                    Jsoup.connect("https://academia.srmist.edu.in/accounts/signin.ac")
                            .data("username", username)
                            .data("password", password)
                            .data("client_portal", client_portal)
                            .data("dcc", dcc)
                            .data("serviceurl", serviceurl)
                            .data("servicename", servicename)
                            .data("portal", portal)
                            .data("service_language", service_language)
                            .data("is_ajax", is_ajax)
                            .data("grant_type", grant_type)
                            .data("_sh", "false")
                            .data("hideidp", "true")
                            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36")
                            .ignoreContentType(true)
                            .execute();




                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://academia.srmist.edu.in/")
                        .cookies(response.cookies()).get();

                str = doc.text();
                Log.d("login", "doinbackground: " + doc.text());

            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I think it requires some OAuthorization as it is one of the first three URLs I see in Network tab in my browser. Also I tried passing JSESSIONID but still not working.

I am new to Jsoup. Can somebody help?

**Here is the main URL of the site:** https://academia.srmist.edu.in/

Comment: What's the error you getting?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I am not getting any error. Log just shows the login page elements i.e., **"academia-academic-services Login Academia - Student Portal Sign In Forgot Password?"**. I can give you my email and password If you need, but please help me with this

Comment: From where did you get all this ".data("...")?

Comment: I saw the form data from Network tab of chrome after inspecting it.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS anything I'm missing here?